# how can i send file with api post method?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my post method , i can send anything with text format but i need to send a file.

if you can, modify just my code. that is easy for catch problem, thanks

```
getComp() async {


final Map<String, dynamic> jsondata = {
  'employee_id':
      '${ScopedModel.of<AppModel>(context, rebuildOnChange: true).employee_id}',
  'receiver_id': '${recid.text}',
  'subject': '${subject.text}',
  'message_body': '${msgbody.text}',
  'message_attachment':'${filePath}'
};
var jsonresponse = null;
var response = await http.post(
    'example.com/compose',
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    body: jsondata,

);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  jsonresponse = json.decode(response.body);
  print(jsonresponse);

}else{
  print('problem');
}
}
```

Here is my file path picker

```
getfile(){

      filePath =  FilePicker.getFilePath(type: FileType.ANY);


}
```

if you can, modify this code .

Answer (score 0):

convert it to base64 first and insert it to the database. That's how I did it when we developed an app that pass a file to the database.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem with dio, :(
if anyone face then use dio

```
 uploadFile() async {
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
  'employee_id':
  '546546',
  'receiver_id': '${recid.text}',
  'subject': '${subject.text}',
  'message_body': '${msgbody.text}',
  'message_attachment': filePath ==null? 'nothing': await 
 MultipartFile.fromFile("${filePath}",filename: "$filePath}"),
});


 Response response = await Dio().post("example.com", data: formData);
 print(response);
}
```